# how to pass a rJava .jnew call multiple parameters?

Tags: java, r, rjava

[the documentation](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/rJava/jnew.html) describes how to pass a single parameter. No worries there. My challenge is trying to pass multiple parameters to java constructors that take them.

For example:

```
foo <- .jnew("some/java/class/that/takes/two/parameters", ???)
```

Comma delimiting doesn't work, nor does putting a space between them. How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document](http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Development#wwjoir) explains how to work with different constructors. See section "*looking up constructors and methods*".

Apparently you have to call the `new()` function instead of / after `.jnew()`.

I'm also still experimenting...

Comment: duuude i so owe you a beer. t/y!